# Fargate container referencing internal localhost

Tags: docker, aws-fargate

I have an AWS Task with a single Container Definition. However, the Docker Image that is used actually runs 3 processes. Now I know this is not best practice, however, this is the situation I am working with.

The problem I am facing is that one of the processes in the container needs to access another internal process. Essentially one java application within the container needs to make a HTTP call using "localhost" to a spring boot application within the same container.

When running the docker images locally there is no problem. However, when deployed as a task in AWS ECS using Fargate, this connection cannot be made. Any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

3 years late, but I just wanted to say that I had to do the same thing today: 2 processes inside the same container, bound to different ports, running on ECS/Fargate. They *are* able to talk to each other using `localhost` as the hostname. The problem must be elsewhere.